# "Undeclared: first use in function error" in while loop despite declaring

Tags: c, gcc

The following code throws the following error when compiled using gcc on a unix machine:

```
eu.c: In function 'main':
eu.c:23: error: 'valuetoAdd' undeclared (first use in this function)
eu.c:23: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
eu.c:23: error: for each function it appears in.)
```

This is the code: I have declared the variable valueToAdd already. Why doesn't it work?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    float input;
    float e = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int flag = 1;
    float valueToAdd = 0.0;

    do
    {
        printf("Enter input: ");
        scanf("%f", &input);
    } while (input < 0);

    while (flag)
    {
        valueToAdd = 1 / factorial(count);
        e += valuetoAdd;
        count++;

        flag = input < valueToAdd;
    }

    printf("The computed value of e is: %.15f", e);
    printf("%d terms were required", count++);

}

int factorial (int c)
{
    if (c == 0) return 1;
    else return c * factorial(c-1);
}
```

Comment: You either need a prototype above main or you need to declare it above main. Also main should return an int.

Comment: I did that it still throws the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `valueToAdd` you are using `valuetoAdd` .. Check case!!

Comment: Haha embarrassing mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you didn't declare `valuetoAdd`. You declared `valueToAdd`, but that's a different identifier. Identifiers are case sensitive in C.

Answer (score 0):

```
valueToAdd = 1 / factorial(count);
e += valuetoAdd;  <= Problem is here, valuetoAdd undeclared !
```